A row of 2 images is not in the middle of screen in React Native
Here is 2 images showing on Android device. the 2 images are not displayed in the middle of the screen. There is a wide gap on the left than the right, even though the paddingLeft is set 0. The gap on the left is larger than the gap on the right.

Here is the code. The screen_width is 97% of the full screen width:
return (
     <View style={{width:"100%", height:screen_width*half,position:"relative", paddingTop:0,paddingLeft:0}}>. //<<==paddingLeft:0
       <RowX2 idx={0} wdh={half} />. //<<==two images shown here by RowX2
     </View>
   ); 


const RowX2 = ({idx, wdh}) => {
    //console.log("RowX2 idx ", idx);
    //console.log("RowX2 wdh ", wdh);
    if (wdh === half) {
        return (           
            <View style={[style.row, {width:screen_width*full, height:screen_width*wdh, flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}]} >. //<<==paddingLeft:0 in style.row
                <ShowImg 
                    img_source={picPath(pics[idx])}
                    gridWidth={screen_width*wdh}
                    gridHt={screen_width*wdh}
                    index= {idx}
                    handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                /> 
                <ShowImg 
                    img_source={picPath(pics[idx+1])}
                    gridWidth={screen_width*wdh}
                    gridHt={screen_width*wdh}
                    index= {idx+1}
                    handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                />                   
            </View>
        );
    } else if (wdh === oneThird) {
        return (           
            <View style={[style.row, {width:screen_width*(1-wdh), height:screen_width*oneThird, flex:1, flexDirection:"row"}]} > //<<==paddingLeft:0 in style.row
                <ShowImg 
                    img_source={picPath(pics[idx])}
                    gridWidth={screen_width*wdh}
                    gridHt={screen_width*wdh}
                    index= {idx}
                    handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                /> 
                <ShowImg 
                    img_source={picPath(pics[idx+1])}
                    gridWidth={screen_width*wdh}
                    gridHt={screen_width*wdh}
                    index= {idx+1}
                    handleSwipe={swipeImage} 
                />             
            </View>
        );
    }
    
};

The style.row is:
row:{
        paddingTop:0,
        paddingLeft:0,
    },


After adding alignContent and alignItems to center in  of return, then the row of 2 images moves to the middle of the screen.
